# The fbs_YOUR_APP_ID not being passed after authentication. Started happening less than 24 hours ago

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

Starting about 20 hours ago,  our web site noticed one thing.  After a user authenticates with FB:Login, the $_REQUEST[fbs_YOUR_APP_ID] is not being passed anymore. As a result, we were not able to get the fb_user_id, etc.

Facebook's current documentation still suggests using $_REQUEST[fbs_YOUR_APP_ID]
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Is it a bug that FB not passing $_REQUEST[fbs_YOUR_APP_ID] any more?

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked doesn't mention $_REQUEST anywhere as far as I can see, it uses _COOKIE near the bottom though?

Did you follow the Oauth and HTTPS migrations ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ ) ? it's been mandatory since Oct 1st but it's only been forced in the last day or so

Comment: Igy,thanks. I meant to say COOKIE ... We debugged and displayed get_facebook_cookie and we also show that it is not being passed.

Comment: Iggy, we echoed $_COOKIE['fbs_139992429401501'] and it is undefined.  So cookie not being passed ....

Comment: And have you updated your code to use the new OAuth 2.0 flows? THe link i gave before is a good summary but you'll really need to check the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ document in detail to know if what you're doing is expected to work

Comment: We var_dump() the $_COOKIE and this is what we got (notice $_COOKIE[fbs_YOURAPPID]  is not set): array(6) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) ......... ["__utmz"]=> string(70) "242848210.1323830563.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)" ["fbsr_139992429401501"]=> string(239) "OQJM4-MDLmrPo9zIS_g2d4uVuTbScmxzWQY3goKRICk.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiIyNmIzZDE2NmQ1MzY5ZTdhMTdhN2MxYmMuMS02ODUxODgzNDJ8YmJBcllTSV9ER0VNUDZzZEw3YTBrTHp4NDlrIiwiaXNzdWVkX2F0IjoxMzIzODczMTQ1LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNjg1MTg4MzQyIn0" }

Comment: Igy, we have followed your authentication docs a long time ago. I think we are good with your suggestion. We just are not sure if we should use $facebook->get_fb_user in our web site fbconnect integration to get the user_id or to follow Facebook's recommendation of using cookies.  If FB wants us to follow using cookies, then it does not seem to work.  If FB wants us to use $facebook-> get_fb_user, it seems to work, but not documented by Facebook as the proper way to do FB Connect on web sites.